# Dynamic LINQ query generation with anonymous types

Tags: c#, .net, linq, reflection

**The following is to provide context, the questions are at the bottom**

I'm attempting to build a completely dynamic api with ASP.NET MVC 4. 
My database is abstracted by LINQ to SQL

My repository class receives an array that represents a rest query, for example
`http://myUrl.com/countries/states/suburbs/24/street/`
turns into the array
`[countries,states,suburbs,24,street]`

I want my repository to then turn that array into something like this (this is pseudo code):
`context.countries.select("states").select("suburbs").where("suburbs.ID == 24").select("street")`

My idea is to loop through the array with a constant object outside of the array with the latest object its up to.

```
object currentContextObj = null;
            object currentUrlPart = null;
            IQueryable<object> queryResult = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < urlArray.Count(); i++)
            {
```

I use reflection to understand on the context to figure out the first bit of the array.

```
if (currentContextObj == null)
                {
                    if (currentUrlPart.GetType() != typeof(string))
                        throw new ArgumentException("URL part '" + currentUrlPart + "' is invalid");

                    currentContextObj = ((IEnumerable<object>)context.GetType().GetProperty((string)currentUrlPart).GetValue(context, null)).AsQueryable();
                }
```

It then exits the loop, the next time around i run a select statement with dynamic linq

```
else if (currentUrlPart.GetType() == typeof(string))
                {

                    currentContextObj = ((IQueryable)currentContextObj).Select((string)currentUrlPart).AsQueryable();

                }
```

This works fine, until it loops through again, on the third part of the array the currentContextObj isnt a queryable, its a data query, if i hover over it when debugging it shows the generated sql statement, so when i run that same `((IQueryable)currentContextObj).Select((string)currentUrlPart).AsQueryable();` it errors:
`No property or field 'Suburbs' exists in type 'EntitySet 1'`.

I am using dynamic linq because the types are all anonymous. My other attempt tried to find the select method of the enumerable class and invoke it on the currentContextObj. that didnt work because the currentContextObj was attempting to cast to an enumerable when it was a table and i couldnt cast to table because i dont know T until runtime.

**I understand this is a lot of information but I will list out what I am asking:**

1. Should I be doing .select().select().where().select()... etc or should i be going .join().join().where().select()
2. Is it possible to avoid this problem i am having with the error for dynamic LINQ?
3. Is there an alternate solution to this problem?

Comment: I would suggest writing some Stored Procs to retrieve the data instead of doing it all with dynamic queries. I assume you know upfront what type of data can be asked for and it should be far easier to just populate the details based on the url segments (or select the correct SP) rather than constructing each query every time a url is hit.

Comment: @Joanna I am attempting to expose majority of my database, i dont want to write specific URLs for each endpoint and all possible inheritance above. Therefore my goal is to create a dynamic repository that can understand the query to make the program really DRY

Comment: Why don't you use odata/WCF data services to expose your database and enable querying?

Comment: Because WCF isn't RESTful, which is a requirement of this application.